# Using USB-MIDI controller in VirtualBox

Tags: fedora, usb, virtualbox

I want to use the Akai MPK 49 master keyboard in a VirtualBox 4.3.28 Windows 7 32bit guest running a Fedora Linux 22 64bit host with kernel version 4.0.4-301. However, Virtualbox doesn't seem to detect the device nether in the device menu when the guest is running, nor in the VirtualBox guest usb settings. According to `dmesg | tail` my linux host detects the device properly. I also installed the VirtualBox guest add-ons and the proprietary expension pack from oracle. I even restarted the whole machine and tried different USB ports - just in case.

What's going wrong here? The controller is working perfectly under native Windows installation.

Edit 1: Yes, I activated the option "Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller" in the VirtualBox guest settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding my user account to the group `vboxusers`.

```
usermod -a -G vboxusers noir
```